# Should I see the same thing when I refresh in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

I was listening to an EmberJS vs AngularJS podcast and the creator of EmberJS commented, "If I refresh and I don't see the same thing, I consider your application broken".

Which makes sense and is ideal I suppose but being somewhat new but am building a very interactive application in angularjs and I've held some stuff in vars but when you refresh you have to click through a few things to make it happen again. (Red flag?)

Is the goal of routing in AngularJS to be able to access vars (/:userId) and when I refresh see see the same exact thing?

***Sidenote: I'm learning ui-router vs Angular's native router atm***

---

#### Update 1

Tom Dale, Peter Cooper and Rob Conery; Cage Match - EmberJS vs. Angular

http://vimeo.com/68215606

HERDING CODE 169: TOM DALE AND ROB CONERY ON THE EMBERJS / ANGULARJS CAGE MATCH AT NDC

http://herdingcode.com/herding-code-169-tom-dale-and-rob-conery-on-the-emberjs-angularjs-cage-match-at-ndc/

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what was that podcast?

Comment: @MichaelBenford I added to my question in the update.

Comment: I thought it was that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

If you use the standard routing like this:

```
<html ng-app="answer">
<body>

<ng-view></ng-view>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('answer', [])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
         $routeProvider.when('/path/:id', {
             controller: 'PathController',
             template: '<div>{{ id }}</div>'
})
.controller('PathController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and

enter the url

```
http://localhost/path/1
```

You will see "1" on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Thats right - routing in angular js (which is even "translated" by google crawler to query string for seo purpose) allows You to view expected output on user refresh. It points which app/controller/view should be used.